# Customizing MetaMask SDK for App Development

Tags: metamask

Is it possible to use the MetaMask SDK source code, replace the icon and name, and generate a working app? If yes, which source code should I use to generate the APK? Additionally, is there any documentation to follow? And, is it appropriate to use this source code directly in this manner?